# $\int^{1/n+1}_{1/n} (\log(1/\theta))^{2}d\theta$ is small for large enough $n$

Tags: real-analysis

I was working on an exercise in Stein & Shakarchi's *Fourier Analysis* which asks us to show that the sequence of functions.

$$f_{n}(\theta)= \begin{cases} 
      0 & 0 \leq x\leq \frac{1}{n} \\          \log(\frac{1}{\theta}) & \frac{1}{n} < x\leq 2\pi \\          
   \end{cases}$$
is Cauchy in the space $\mathcal{R}$ of Riemann integrable functions defined on $[0, 2\pi]$.
**This is essentially the same as showing that 
 $\int^{1/n+1}_{1/n} (\log(1/\theta))^{2}d\theta$ is small for large enough $n$**

> More precisely, if we set $$a_{n}= \int^{1/n+1}_{1/n} (\log(1/\theta))^{2}d\theta$$ for each $n$, we  want to show that
>   $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n}=   0$$

I've tried doing this by squeezing the sequence $(a_{n})$. In particular, I've noticed that using the definition of the Riemann integral, we have that $a_{n} \leq \log^{2}(n+1)({1}/{n}-{1}/{(n+1)})$. I know that if we show $$\log^{2}(n+1)({1}/{n}-{1}/{(n+1)} )\to 0$$
than I'll be done. I want to use that $\log(1/\theta)$ is convex (concave up) somehow but I'm confused on the estimate.

Also, maybe one could compute the antiderivative of $\log^{2}(1/\theta)$ (maybe using integration by parts or something like that), but I decided that the estimate might be easier.

**Remark:**

*This exercise is one way of showing that $\mathcal{R}$ is not complete.*

Comment: $\frac1n - \frac1{n+1} = \frac1{n(n+1)}$, and then use L'Hopital? Not sure about your question...

Comment: Note that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \int_0^1 \log^2(\theta) \, d\theta = 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is that
$\log(n)/n \to 0$
and
$1/n-1/(n+1)=1/(n(n+1))$.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I was thinking too hard.